Android java service connect to unix socket created by vendor hal
I have a vendor hal which crates unix socket.
I have a java service which connects to the socket created by vendor hal.
Java service can not connect to the socket because violation of sepolicy:
05-31 02:50:29.494  2598  2598 W testservice: type=1400 audit(0.0:159): avc: denied { connectto } for path=006F6E657761792E736F636B65745F737276 scontext=u:r:system_app:s0 tcontext=u:r:hal_test:s0 tclass=unix_stream_socket permissive=0

According to audit2allow i have to add seplicy rule:
allow system_app hal_test:unix_stream_socket connectto;

But Android build failed because of:
libsepol.check_assertions: 1 neverallow failures occurred

Extra info related to neverallow rule defined in system/sepolicy/public/domain.te:
# On full TREBLE devices, socket communications between core components and vendor components are
# not permitted.
  # Most general rules first, more specific rules below.

  # Core domains are not permitted to initiate communications to vendor domain sockets.
  # We are not restricting the use of already established sockets because it is fine for a process
  # to obtain an already established socket via some public/official/stable API and then exchange
  # data with its peer over that socket. The wire format in this scenario is dicatated by the API
  # and thus does not break the core-vendor separation.
full_treble_only(`
  neverallow_establish_socket_comms({
    coredomain
    -init
    -adbd
  }, {
    domain
    -coredomain
    -socket_between_core_and_vendor_violators
  });
')

Is there any way to properly use unix socket from java service ? Socket is created by vendor hal.

I solved the problem by adding rule:
typeattribute hal_test socket_between_core_and_vendor_violators;

This is just workaround by in my case this is OK.
